# TestNG - What is the default value of thread-count, if not specified in testng xml?

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

For below TestNG XML file, I am not specifying the thread-count explicitly. What is the default value of thread count for the below XML?

```
<suite name="TmpSuite" >
  <test name="TmpTest" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.failures.Child"  />
    </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the value of the thread-count is **5**.

You can check it by entering the text `thread-count` corresponding to the `suite` attribute in the testng file and then you can hit `Control + Space` to get the auto-suggest for the thread-count and you would be able to see the default value for the thread-count.

Please check the attached screenshot for your reference.

[image: Thread Count Default Value]

Comment: Yes, I see the value at http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php as "thread-count CDATA "5"", so it's prepopulating. This must be an assumption. Do we have any written documentation anywhere regarding this?

Comment: I checked the official documentation of testng here: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html , though i did not find the default value on that page.